# Best framework for html5 mobile?

Tags: html, css, cordova

Looking to use phonegap to build an html5 based mobile app.  Does anyone know the best framework to use to work on many types of different mobile devices.  It will not be accessed via computer, only mobile.

Comment: There is no "best framework", there are frameworks that fill your needs. 
http://www.markus-falk.com/mobile-frameworks-comparison-chart/ Explain them is you need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AngularJS :**

It is a great JavaScript framework that has some very compelling features for not only developers, but designers as well! So you use this framework to build your mobile app

Comment: oooh... and its by Google.  I will check this out.